# Russian hyphenation with polyglossia

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia, cyrillic, russian

I want to forbid hyphenation of less than three letters by doing `\providehyphenmins{russian}{{3}{3}}`. But it doesn't work.
[image]

Looking through complation messages gives[image]

How can this be fixed?

If it matters, I compile with LuaLaTeX, version of LuaTeX is 1.0.4.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\providehyphenmins{russian}{{3}{3}}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
    Зрительная коммуникация у слоновых в основном предполагает агрессию. 
Слоны стараются казаться более угрожающими, подымая голову и расправляя уши. 
К этому по необходимости могут быть добавлены качания головы, хлопанье ушами и швыряние земли и растительности.
Возбуждённые слоны поднимают хобот вверх.
 Особи, готовые подчиниться, опускают голову и хобот, а уши поджимают к шее, а те кто принимает вызов вытягивают уши
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (not that I deem it intuitive):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\PolyglossiaSetup{russian}{hyphenmins={3,3}}

\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}


\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}% force maximal hyphenation
Лорем ипсум долор
етиам аццусам цомплецтитур
проприае волуптуа
еяуидем цонсеяуат
еирмод индоцтум пхилосопхиа
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I have understood is that that the hyphenation setup should be done *before* the main language is set. Then yours and mine works. Otherwise, both don't work.

I also wonder if there is a documentation of `polyslossia`, because `texdoc polyglossia` gives quite a short document with no `Polyglossiasetup` in it.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I believe that `PolyglossiaSetup` was added a short time before F. Charette abandoned the project, so it remained in a limbo.

Comment: `providehyphenmins` still works, so maybe `Polyglossiasetup` is no needed.