# Is the documentation for polyglossia complete?

Tags: babel, polyglossia

The documentation for `polyglossia` located on CTAN takes 17 pages, while `babel` documentation is (without the desription of the code) about 50 pages. Also there are a lot of documents `babel-<language>` to describe some specific stuff about the language.

As pointed out in the answer [Russian hyphenation with polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374646/russian-hyphenation-with-polyglossia) there is at least one undocumented feature.

Are there any other undocumented features or does `polyglossia` rely on `babel` in some way such as using shortands defined by `babel-<language>`?

Comment: I previously commented about the weird dormant state of `polyglossia` development/maintenance here. Recently there has been a lot of work on `polyglossia` so I have removed that comment to avoid confusion by outdated information. At least at the moment `polyglossia` should be considered to be (very) actively maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original developer left the project a while ago and the current maintainer took over the job. It could be that some features that were implemented shortly before the original author left the project were not documented in the manual.

I'm not a `babel`/`polyglossia` expert but it is not impossible that due to the different implementations and the relative maturity of `babel` there is more to document on the `babel` side, hence its documentation is longer.

Comment: Thank you for providing some info, but I think I will wait a few days before accepting the answer.